# Split pandas df rows into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a csv that I needed to split on \n because because of the file type. After separating this df into two separate dfs I am left with rows that look like this

```
27  Block\t"Column"\t"Row"\t"X"\t"Y"\t"Dia."\t"Fla...
28  1\t1\t1\t17834.00\t38902.00\t10.00\t0\t513.27\...
29  1\t2\t1\t17852.00\t38902.00\t10.00\t0\t495.84\...
30  1\t3\t1\t17870.00\t38902.00\t10.00\t0\t525.76\...
31  1\t4\t1\t17888.00\t38902.00\t10.00\t0\t456.27\...
```

How can I create columns from the delimiter \t ?

Comment: So I already read in the file with .read_csv but had to delimitate on \n and then split the dataframe into two separate dataframes. I no longer have a csv file, I have a df so is there a way to do this without writing it to a separate csv and re-reading it on \t?

Answer (score 0):

Something lke this might be what you're looking for...

```
df['Block'] = df['Block'].str.split('/t').str[0]
df['Column'] = df['Columnl'].str.split('/t').str[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
df[['Block','Column', 'Row', 'X', 'Y', etc]] = df['<Column Name>'].str.split(r'\t',expand=True)
```

Replace `etc` with the rest of the column names. Replace `<Column Name>` with the name of the column when you print the df.

A simpler method might be to download the dataframe as a csv, then reread it with a `\t` delimiter.

Comment: Is there a way I can directly use the first row as column headers without rewriting them?

Comment: You should be able to use list comprehension. I'll need to try it out and then update my answer. One sec

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work, so I updated my answer with an alternative.